# Unpredictable results using cut() function in R to convert dates to 15 minute intervals

Tags: r

OK, this is making me crazy.

I have several datasets with time values that need to be rolled up into 15 minute intervals.

I found a solution here that works beautifully on one dataset. But on the next one I try to do I'm getting weird results. I have a column with character data representing dates:

```
                 BeginTime
-------------------------------
    1           1/3/19 1:50 PM
    2           1/3/19 1:30 PM
    3           1/3/19 4:56 PM
    4          1/4/19 11:23 AM
    5           1/6/19 7:45 PM
    6          1/7/19 10:15 PM
    7          1/8/19 12:02 PM
    8          1/9/19 10:43 PM
```

And I'm using the following code (which is exactly what I used on the other dataset except for the names)

```
df$by15 = cut(mdy_hm(df$BeginTime), breaks="15 min")
```

but what I get is:

```
                    BeginTime              by15
-------------------------------------------------------
    1           1/3/19 1:50 PM      2019-01-03 13:36:00
    2           1/3/19 1:30 PM      2019-01-03 13:21:00
    3           1/3/19 4:56 PM      2019-01-03 16:51:00
    4          1/4/19 11:23 AM      2019-01-04 11:21:00
    5           1/6/19 7:45 PM      2019-01-06 19:36:00
    6          1/7/19 10:15 PM      2019-01-07 22:06:00
    7          1/8/19 12:02 PM      2019-01-08 11:51:00
    8          1/9/19 10:43 PM      2019-01-09 22:36:00
    9         1/10/19 11:25 AM      2019-01-10 11:21:00
```

Any suggestions on why I'm getting such random times instead of the 15-minute intervals I'm looking for? Like I said, this worked fine on the other data set.

Comment: You don't include the full source code to create `df`.  When I create it by copying your data, I don't see the results you showed.  So I'd guess something you did isn't being told to us.

Comment: Can you show what is your expected output ?

Comment: I suspect the `by15` output starts with the earliest value and adds 15 min increments from there. You might alternatively use `df$by15 = floor_date(mdy_hm(df$BeginTime), "15 min")`.  (I assume you have `lubridate` loaded already for `mdy_hm`.)

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring...that worked.

Comment: @user2554330, I am importing from a csv so if you got different results by creating the df from scratch then perhaps the issue is with the file somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lubridate::round_date() function which will roll-up your datetime data as follows;

```
library(lubridate) # To handle datetime data
library(dplyr) # For data manipulation

# Creating dataframe
df <-
  data.frame(
    BeginTime = c("1/3/19 1:50 PM", "1/3/19 1:30 PM", "1/3/19 4:56 PM",
                  "1/4/19 11:23 AM", "1/6/19 7:45 PM", "1/7/19 10:15 PM",
                  "1/8/19 12:02 PM", "1/9/19 10:43 PM")
  )

df %>%
  # First we parse the data in order to convert it from string format to datetime
  mutate(by15 = parse_date_time(BeginTime, '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p'),
         # We roll up the data/round it to 15 minutes interval
         by15 = round_date(by15, "15 mins"))
# 
# BeginTime                by15
# 1/3/19 1:50 PM   2019-03-01 13:45:00
# 1/3/19 1:30 PM   2019-03-01 13:30:00
# 1/3/19 4:56 PM   2019-03-01 17:00:00
# 1/4/19 11:23 AM  2019-04-01 11:30:00
# 1/6/19 7:45 PM   2019-06-01 19:45:00
# 1/7/19 10:15 PM  2019-07-01 22:15:00
# 1/8/19 12:02 PM  2019-08-01 12:00:00
# 1/9/19 10:43 PM  2019-09-01 22:45:00
```